Issue with Next.js build failing in GitHub Actions but working locally, followed by Cloud Run deployment error
Issue with Next.js build failing in GitHub Actions but working locally, followed by Cloud Run deployment error
Hi, I'm facing a series of issues related to my Next.js app build and deployment process. Initially, the build worked fine locally using npm run build, but when running the build through GitHub Actions, I encountered the following error (Problem ①). After modifying the Dockerfile and GitHub Actions configuration to resolve this, I started facing another issue during deployment to Cloud Run (Problem ②).
Problem 1: GitHub Actions build error
Warning: React Hook useCallback has missing dependencies: 'analyses', 'axiosClient', and 'goToProjectChattingPage'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Error: <Html> should not be imported outside of pages/_document.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-document-import-in-page

Dockerfile Error: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Here’s the Dockerfile I’m using for the build:
FROM node:16-alpine AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci

FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
RUN rm .env.production
RUN mv .env.development .env.production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1
ENV NODE_ENV development
RUN npm run build

FROM node:16-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV development
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1
RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static
USER nextjs
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "server.js"]

Here’s the .yml file for GitHub Actions:
name: Deploy frontend

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - "frontend/**"
      - .github/workflows/deploy-frontend.yaml
  release:
    types:
      - published

permissions:
  contents: read
  id-token: write

jobs:
  build-and-push:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/build-and-push-rerunnable.yaml
    with:
      docker_image: terraform/images/front
      gcp_project_id: clnr-${{ (github.event_name == 'release' && 'prod') || 'dev' }}
      dockerfile: ./frontend/Dockerfiles/Dockerfile_${{ (github.event_name == 'release' && 'prod') || 'dev' }}
      context: ./frontend
    secrets: inherit

  deploy:
    name: Deploy to CloudRun
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
        name: ${{ (github.event_name == 'release' && 'prod') || 'dev' }}
        url: https://${{ (github.event_name == 'release' && 'org') || 'dev' }}
    needs:
      - build-and-push
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: google-github-actions/auth@v2
        with:
          workload_identity_provider: ${{ secrets.WIF_PROVIDER }}
          service_account: github-actions@clnr-${{ (github.event_name == 'release' && 'prod') || 'dev' }}.iam.gserviceaccount.com
      - name: Deploy to CloudRun
        uses: google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@v1
        with:
          project_id: clnr-${{ (github.event_name == 'release' && 'prod') || 'dev' }}
          service: front
          image: ${{ needs.build-and-push.outputs.image_url }}
          region: asia-northeast1

Problem 2: Cloud Run deployment error
After fixing the Dockerfile and GitHub Actions configuration, the build succeeds, but I encounter the following error when deploying to Cloud Run:
Error: google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun failed with: failed to execute gcloud command gcloud run deploy my-service --quiet --update-labels managed-by=github-actions,commit-sha=e0c60a1f74ea83028bcceb0b3ccc4d198a4d50a4 --platform managed --format json --region asia-northeast1 --project dev-project: ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Missing required argument [--image]: Requires a container image to deploy (e.g. gcr.io/cloudrun/hello:latest) if no build source is provided.

This is my updated Dockerfile:
FROM node:18-alpine AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci

FROM node:18-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
RUN rm .env.production
RUN mv .env.development .env.production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1
ENV NODE_ENV development
RUN npm run build

FROM node:18-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1
RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static
USER nextjs
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "server.js"]

Here’s the relevant part of the updated .yml file for GitHub Actions:
name: Deploy frontend

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - feat/fix-front-build
    paths:
      - "frontend/**"
      - .github/workflows/deploy-frontend.yaml
  release:
    types:
      - published

permissions:
  contents: read
  id-token: write

jobs:
  build-and-push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      # Use npm cache
      - name: Cache node modules
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: frontend/node_modules
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('frontend/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-node-

      # Install dependencies
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci
        working-directory: ./frontend

      # Clear cache if needed (manual trigger or conditional)
      - name: Clear npm cache if needed
        if: ${{ failure() }} # Clear cache if the build fails
        run: npm cache clean --force
        working-directory: ./frontend

      # Use Next.js build cache
      - name: Cache Next.js build cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: frontend/.next/cache
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-nextjs-${{ hashFiles('frontend/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-nextjs-

      # Run the build
      - name: Build frontend
        run: npm run build
        working-directory: ./frontend

  deploy:
    name: Deploy to CloudRun
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
      name: ${{ (github.event_name == 'release' && 'prod') || 'dev' }}
      url: https://test.${{ (github.event_name == 'release' && 'org') || 'dev' }}
    needs:
      - build-and-push
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: google-github-actions/auth@v2
        with:
          workload_identity_provider: ${{ secrets.WIF_PROVIDER }}
          service_account: github-actions@${{ (github.event_name == 'release' && 'prod') || 'dev' }}-test.iam.gserviceaccount.com
      - name: Deploy to CloudRun
        uses: google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@v1
        with:
          project_id: ${{ (github.event_name == 'release' && 'prod') || 'dev' }}
          service: test-front
          image: ${{ needs.build-and-push.outputs.image_url }}
          region: asia-northeast1

What I've tried:

I addressed the useCallback dependency warning, but the error persists.
I’ve updated the Dockerfile and GitHub Actions YAML file, and the build passes now, but the Cloud Run deployment fails due to the missing --image argument.

I would greatly appreciate any advice on how to resolve these issues!
